# How do I check if button was pressed past 5 seconds or so?

Tags: javascript, angular

How do you limit how much a user can press a button in angular 2? So that they can't spam the update button which spams the db.

For example, a user should be able to press the update button every 5 seconds if they wanted to.

My  guess would be to set a `new Date()` variable and then check the date with a new date  to see if it was pressed 5 seconds ago. How do you check that?

Comment: Just set a disabled variable to true once the user click, and on the callback/after a setTimeout for 5s set it back to false ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Comment: Ok, that worked. I didn't think about using the disabled variable. Thanks!